# How to download and stock a jar file into internal storage?

Tags: java, android, jar, nullpointerexception, download

I am trying to download a jar file from my server and put it into the AVD internal memory but it's not working. I tried this code in Java and it's working perfectly.

```
try
        {
            URL url = new URL(host);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            if (fileLength == -1)
            {
                return;
            }

            input = connection.getInputStream();
            String fileName = url.getFile().substring(url.getFile().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            writeFile = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;

            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0)
                writeFile.write(buffer, 0, read);
            writeFile.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                writeFile.close();
                input.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I add the following permission into my manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But on connection.getContentLength();, I got a NullPointerException return

I tried with HttpURLConnection and JarURLConnection, add a connection.connect() just after openConnection(), using DownloadManager but it can only download into external storage.

Maybe with HttpClient ? AndroidHttpClient ? But Android support recommend using HttpURLConnection for applications targeted at Gingerbread and higher.

Answer (score 0):

There's a cumbersome but straightforward approach: 
 1. Use `DownloadManager` to get a JAR you need (store it in external storage); 
 2. Move that JAR from external storage to internal one.

Comment: Yeah it can work, but if there is no external storage enable ?

Comment: Did you check if the `url` is valid?

Comment: Yes, I am sur it is valide !

Comment: Let me get it right: your current problem is NullPointerException on `connection.getContentLength();` statement, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use JarURLConnection again maybe I just miss used it.